# Find values in range and print to column

Tags: vba, excel

How can I generate the Excel as in the image below via a macro?
Briefly I would like to make:

- numbers between a1 and b1 print to d column;
- numbers between a2 and b2 print to e column;
- numbers between a3 and b3 print to f column.

Columns A and B have thousands of values.

[image: excel rows mahmut]

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA answer? There might be a formula solution. Quickly: If you copy your column A, then paste (transpose) in D, you'll get a list...then, in D2, you can do `=IF(AND(D1<>"",D1<>$B$1),D1+1,"")` ...the only thing is, I don't know how to get that to drag over and correctly update what row/column to look at.

Comment: For next loop, for i=range("a1").value to range("b1").value.  You'll need a counter for the row number.

Comment: I ran some tests on over 10,000 rows.  Ranking in speed from quickest to slowest, 1. tigeravatar, 2.Mine(ScottCraner), 3.Jeeped, 4.Manu, 5, BruceWayne.  Actual results may vary slightly.

Comment: Unfortunately you can only choose one as "Correct".  Choose the one that you use as correct.  None of us will get our feelings hurt,  this was fun and that is reward enough.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Aw boo - my method is just quick and dirty so I didn't think to minimize time. I assume it takes long because of the assignments and loop? I'm surprised that Tiger's is quickest - I need to learn how to make my code more efficient...

Comment: One more note, **usually** questions that show little effort on the part of the one posing the question get down voted.  This just happened to be a fun puzzle that turned into a challenge.  The next question posed should show some code that was tried and what specifically is going wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only because I like puzzles:

```
Sub u5758()
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim oArr() As Variant
Dim arr() As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet

x = 4
With ws
oArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).value
    For j = LBound(oArr, 1) To UBound(oArr, 1)
        ReDim arr(oArr(j, 1) To oArr(j, 2))
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            arr(i) = i
        Next i
        .Cells(1, x).Resize(UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1).value = Application.Transpose(arr)
        x = x + 1
    Next j
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. This really helps. Thank you so much. You are an  incredibe man Scott.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, here is a formula solution:

```
=IF(ROW(D1)>INDEX($A:$B,COLUMN(D1)-COLUMN($C1),2)-INDEX($A:$B,COLUMN(D1)-COLUMN($C1),1)+1,"",INDEX($A:$B,COLUMN(D1)-COLUMN($C1),1)+ROW(D1)-1)
```

Though I realize that a formula solution may not be feasible based on this statement:

> Columns A and B have thousands of values.

**EDIT**: Pure array VBA solution:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim lMaxDiff As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rIndex As Long, cIndex As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rData = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    lMaxDiff = Evaluate("MAX(" & rData.Columns(2).Address(external:=True) & "-" & rData.Columns(1).Address(external:=True) & ")") + 1
    aData = rData.Value2
    ReDim aResults(1 To lMaxDiff, 1 To rData.Rows.Count)

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        If IsNumeric(aData(i, 1)) And IsNumeric(aData(i, 2)) Then
            rIndex = 0
            cIndex = cIndex + 1
            For j = Int(aData(i, 1)) To Int(aData(i, 2))
                rIndex = rIndex + 1
                aResults(rIndex, cIndex) = j
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    ws.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend.

Comment: Woww.İt's really quick.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
 Sub test()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim j As Double, i As Double, r As Double
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change the name of your sheet

Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

j = 4 ' Column D

With ws

For i = 1 To Lastrow ' Start the loop at A1 until the last row in column A

    .Cells(1, j) = .Cells(i, 1).Value

r = 1

    Do
        .Cells(r + 1, j) = .Cells(r, j) + 1
        r = r + 1

    Loop Until .Cells(r, j) = .Cells(i, 2).Value

    j = j + 1

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you assign `Lastrow` to be the last row in column A on Sheet1, you really shouldn't rely on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for all of the cell references. A quick [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to wrap around the bulk of the code would take care of this.

Comment: Now you need to put a `.` in front of all your `Cells(...`;  `.Cells(1, j) = .Cells(i, 1).Value`

Comment: Thank you Jeeped and Scott Craner I really appreciate your advise!

Comment: I really appreciate your help. This really helps. Thank you so much. You are increadibe man too.

Answer (score 2):

I like puzzles too.

```
Sub from_here_to_there()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet5")  '<~~ set this worksheet properly!
        For rw = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(rw, 1)) And IsNumeric(.Cells(rw, 2)) Then
                With .Columns(Application.Max(4, .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1))
                    .Cells(1, 1) = .Parent.Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                    .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
                        Step:=1, Stop:=.Parent.Cells(rw, 2).Value2
                End With
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: number_series]

Comment: I really appreciate your help. This really helps. Thank you so much. You are increadibe man too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another quick one just for fun:

```
Sub transposeNfill()
Dim lastRow&, i&, xStart$, xEnd$, xMid$

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    xStart = Cells(i, 1)
    xEnd = Cells(i, 2)
    xMid = xEnd - xStart
    Cells(1, i + 3).Value = xStart
    Cells(1 + xMid, i + 3) = xEnd
    Range(Cells(2, i + 3), Cells(xMid, i + 3)).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c+1"
    Cells.Copy
    Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: wonderful. thank you so much. is it possible all results in one column?

Comment: @user5758125 - That would be considered an adjustment to the original question that invalidates all previous valid solutions and is typically frowned upon. If you have a new question, please start a new question.

Comment: @user5758125 Just an FYI, and nothing against Bruce, but this was the slowest by a factor of 1000.  Tigaravatar took less than 5 seconds to parse over 10,000 rows.  I stopped this one after 4 minutes and it only had done 390 rows.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Holy cow, how many rows did you try this on (how many "couples" of numbers)?  I knew mine would be slower, but jeeeeez.  Is there a quick explanation as to what makes Tigeravatar's so much faster, despite the longer code? (And yeah, I know code length doesn't always translate to speed, but it's a bit more with the variables, so I'm curious how he got it to be so speedy).

Comment: He loaded everything into arrays, manipulated the array into another array then assigned the array to the sheet. I did this too, but I assigned every row. Yours interacts with the sheet constantly, this slows it down.  Plus the fact that your inputting formulas then copying and pasting the values slows it down.  Manu and Jeeped though they also interact with the sheet, assigned the values directly without copy and paste or formulas.  Usually, the less going back and forth between the sheet and vba the faster the process.

Comment: I did 10500 rows of 99 in A and 1000 in B

Comment: In that case, I use Tigeravatar's.

Comment: @mahmutziya then that is the one that should be marked as correct.  Again My, and I assume Bruce's, feelings will not be hurt.  But I agree that tigeravatar's  approach is the fastest.

Comment: Scott Craner Thank you so much. Again and again.

Comment: @ScottCraner - That makes sense after looking at it. Thanks a lot for the detail!! (and my feelings are still intact :P)